# Rotation Forest Classifier using WEKA GUI-how do I identify incorrectly classified instances

Tags: instance, classification, weka

I am using WEKA GUI for classification using default WEKA settings. I am getting certain number of incorrectly classified instances. How do I identify the instances that are incorrectly classified. I tried to add an additional string id , but this additional attribute is also used by the classifier as a feature and hence it affects classification efficiency. I am not sure how to identify the incorrectly classified instances without affecting the classification accuracy.

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful here

Comment: May be my question is not clear. Please ignore the portion on "additional string id". I have some data that I feed into WEKA GUI for classification. I am able to get usual results with number of correctly classified instance and number of incorrectly classified instances.  How do I identify the instances that are not correctly classified. The standard WEKA output does not tell me which instances are incorrectly classified.    I am using Rotation Forest with J48 for classification -all through WEKA GUI.

Answer (score 0):

In the Weka GUI under the "Classify tab", in the "Test options" column, there is a "More options..." button.  After pressing that button there is a new window with one option to "Output predictions".  This will print the prediction for each test instance and allow you to identify the misclassified instances.

[image]

Comment: I did that. I can see the predicted and actual values.  Still it doesn't show the instances (id) that were incorrectly classified.